# Flutter State different behaviour between child elements of ListView.Builder and Column

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I have tried adapting some examples after watching this tutorial for Keys in Flutter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc

Altough i'm using uniqueKey(), when using ListView.Builder to lay out the tiles the state object is created everytime for the two swapped widget elements. If i use a column to display the widgets it does keep the state. The code besides the different UI-Element is identical. Here is a MRE:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainApp> createState() => _MainAppState();
}

class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  late List<Widget> tiles;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tiles = [
      ColorTile(key: UniqueKey()),
      ColorTile(key: UniqueKey()),
      ColorTile(key: UniqueKey()),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build outside');
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: swapTiles),
        /* body: Column(
          children: tiles,
        ), */
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: tiles.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return tiles[index];
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void swapTiles() {
    setState(() {
      tiles.insert(2, tiles.removeAt(1));
    });
  }
}

class ColorTile extends StatefulWidget {
  const ColorTile({super.key});

  @override
  State<ColorTile> createState() => _ColorTileState();
}

class _ColorTileState extends State<ColorTile> {
  final Color color = Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("build ColorTile..., key: ${widget.key}");
    return Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      color: color,
    );
  }
}
```

According to all information i could find, if the widgettype and the key are identical, then Flutter doesn't dispose of the state object on the element tree. However with ListView.builder seemingly a new state object is created everytime when the swap-button is pressed.

Why is that ?

Dart SDK version: 3.0.3 (stable),
Flutter 3.10.3 • channel stable

Answer (score 0):

The state remains consistent for all Tiles, but each time you invoke `setState`, a new random color is applied to it. To resolve this, you can extract the **Colors** from the `Tile` widget class and pass them to a constructor. This way, random colors will only be generated once when the `parent widget` is executed. If you call `setState` while swapping tiles, it won't affect the color state.

Example is given below:

```
    import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainApp> createState() => _MainAppState();
}

class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  late List<Widget> tiles;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    tiles = [
      ColorTile(  color:   Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
  key: UniqueKey()),
      ColorTile(color:   Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)], key: UniqueKey()),
      ColorTile(color:   Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)], key: UniqueKey()),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build outside');
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: swapTiles),
        /* body: Column(
          children: tiles,
        ), */
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: tiles.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return tiles[index];
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void swapTiles() {
    setState(() {
      tiles.insert(2, tiles.removeAt(1));
    });
  }
}

class ColorTile extends StatefulWidget {
  const ColorTile({required this.color,super.key});
final Color color;
  @override
  State<ColorTile> createState() => _ColorTileState();
}

class _ColorTileState extends State<ColorTile> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("build ColorTile..., key: ${widget.key}");
    return Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      color:widget. color,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer my question at all. The question is not how to keep the color, but why flutter behaves differently than all tutorial videos and officical documentation tells us.
If you take my MRE and compare column and listview (both provided, one is commented out), you will see that using Column the State is kept and swapped correctly. Using ListView.builder new state is generated everytime we press swap. According to official documentation it should not create new state.